# Swift: How do I repeat a getDoc request to Firestore?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can already check if a doc exists in a collection. However I am unable to repeatedly check the same collection while trying different path names.

For example, my collection name is the UID of the user. There can be an unlimited amount of docs in this collection. The docs are titled "UID-0", "UID-1", "UID-2" and so on as the user adds items.

Every time it finds a doc that already exists such as "UID-0" it will change the path request to "UID-+=1" until the number exceeds the docs and it is able to create and use that path name.

Each doc contains about a dozen fields of the same data model but of course different data.

```
var docAlreadyExists: Bool = true
var multipleUserFencesIdCount: Int = 0
var newID: String = ""
let id = self.auth.currentUser?.uid ?? ""

repeat {
print("1")
self.fencesInfoCollection.document("Live").collection(id).document(newID).getDocument(completion: { document, error in
print("2")
    if let document = document, document.exists {
        print("EXISTS")
        multipleUserFencesIdCount += 1
        newID = newID.dropLast() + "\(multipleUserFencesIdCount)"
    } else {
        print("DOES NOT EXIST")
        docAlreadyExists = false
    }
})
} while docAlreadyExists
```

With that said, how can I repeatedly check if a document exists until the path name exceeds the rest and is able to create a new doc with the new data.

Edit:

The 1 gets repeatedly called correctly but the .getDoc never calls since 2 is never printed.

Comment: I would change the approach. It appears you are creating documentID's that are unique by finding an existing one and adding 1 to the name to then write the new data. Let Firestore do the heavy lifting by creating unique documentID's for you. See [Add a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document)

Comment: @jay I ended up completing changing my data structure so I dont event need to do this anymore, but at least if someone else is wondering they have a solution now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a better solution to my goal, instead of trying to repeat a call with different IDs I am now getting all documents and counting how many are in the collection.

```
self.fencesInfoCollection.document(id).collection("Live").getDocuments(completion: { document, error in
                    if let document = document, document.isEmpty {
                        print("EMPTY")
                    } else {
                        print("DOC1: \(String(describing: document?.count))")
                    }
                })
```

Comment: While this *may* be a solution, it won't scale well. Imagine 10,000 documents in that collection; the code reads *all* of them in! That will not only be laggy for the user, especially if it's done frequently, it will also cost a fortune over time and if the collection get's larger, could overwhelm the device and cause random crashes. A more practical, less costly and fast approach is to keep a collection that stores the document count of this collection. When a document is added or removed increment/decrement the count. Do that in a transaction so it all stays sync'd.

Comment: Great suggestion. In my new data structure I am using .whereField() to do a similar task, which is good for scaling